# is it possible to convert dataset to sparse volume (thin provisioning)?

Tags: zfs, thin-provisioning

I've created ZFS datasets and installed virtual servers into them. Suddenly my ZFS volume free space is gone, but not all space is used in each dataset. I want to introduce thin provisioning (use ZFS sparse volume).

Is it possible to convert datasets into sparse volumes without deleting them? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to convert an existing zvol to sparse; they must be created sparse to begin with.

However, you can create a new sparse zvol, and `zfs send` from the old one and `zfs recv` to the new one, and then swap their names.

Comment: Isn't this command `zfs set refreservation=none tank/dataset` same as send and receive?

Comment: There is some article about it - http://nex7.blogspot.cz/2013/03/reservation-ref-reservation-explanation.html

Comment: Can you actually do that?

Comment: Yes, I've done that and it's working okay.

Comment: @Xdg Hm, I think if you do that then you also need to make sure `reservation` is also set to none.

Answer (score 11):

I don't think the accepted answer is correct in fact, but I don't have enough rep to comment.

Assuming when the OP says "datasets" they mean "ZFS volume" (or ZVOL).

The only difference between a thin-provisioned (a.k.a sparse) ZVOL and a regular one is whether the full size is reserved via the `refreservation` property e.g.

```
# zfs create -V 10G tank/test_full
# zfs create -s -V 10G tank/test_sparse
# zfs list -o name,used,usedbydataset,usedbyrefreservation,logicalused,logicalreferenced,refreservation tank/test_sparse tank/test_full
NAME               USED  USEDDS  USEDREFRESERV  LUSED  LREFER  REFRESERV
tank/test_full    10.3G    136K          10.3G    30K     30K      10.3G
tank/test_sparse   136K    136K              0    30K     30K       none
```

So you **can** convert an existing ZVOL to sparse by changing `refreservation` for an existing ZVOL e.g.

```
# zfs set refreservation=none tank/test_full
# zfs list -o name,used,usedbydataset,usedbyrefreservation,logicalused,logicalreferenced,refreservation tank/test_sparse tank/test_full
NAME               USED  USEDDS  USEDREFRESERV  LUSED  LREFER  REFRESERV
tank/test_full     136K    136K              0    30K     30K       none
tank/test_sparse   136K    136K              0    30K     30K       none
```